# bootstrap-select + typescript + webpack doesnt render properly on simple example

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-select

i got the following result on the browser. and i'm not sure why.

[image]
Here is the HTML

```xml
<body>
  <select id="selectpicker">
    <option>Mustard</option>
    <option>Ketchup</option>
    <option>Barbecue</option>
  </select>  
</body>
```

Here is the typescript

```js
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'

import $ from 'jquery';
import 'bootstrap'
import 'bootstrap-select';


$(function () {
    $('#selectpicker').selectpicker();
});
```

How do I make this work?

**EDIT: SOLVED!!** i did not know that i need to `import 'bootstrap-select/dist/css/bootstrap-select.css'` as well.

Comment: if possible please share the error you see in console.

Comment: @ThisisFish no errors in the console

Comment: please share the compiled (relevant!) html + css. You are using bootstrap-select css, and not only bootstrap-css, right?

Comment: ah.. i didn't import the bootstrap-select css. they should have mentioned it in the docs

Answer (score 2):

include `import 'bootstrap-select/dist/css/bootstrap-select.css'` in the ts file